# Beautiful typeset books with computer code

Tags: typography, code, books, examples

I am at putting together a manuscript with a fair amount of computer code. I have a fair understanding of LaTex and will use it for typesetting.

Can I please ask for your recommedations re printed books where you consider the integration of text and code typograpically of high quality?

One book I consider "state of the art" is Jim Felici: The Complete Manual of Typography: A Guide to Setting Perfect Type", (PeachPress 2012). Another I consider typograpically "above average" is Barry Cunliffe: "By Desert, Steppe, Ocean: The Birth of Eurasia", (OUP 2117, paper). OUP has several titles by Cunliffe, all with the same overall design, but differing in small details. Putting them next to each other, it is easy to see the effects. I am aware of the "classics", like Tufte, Bringhurst and others. 
Thank you.

Comment: For code in LaTeX, there's `listings` and `minted`(a wrapper for a Python script). In case you consider ConTeXt, there's `t-vim` (a wrapper for Vim coloring).

Comment: `tcolorbox` is much fancier.

Comment: Thank you, both. Maybe my question was not clear. I am looking for **printed** books with computer code, to study the typographical details. The typography of book should be of **high quality**.